# How to run multiple functions condition in every item of array based on multi checkbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I been searching for days how to create this.

Here's what the multi checkbox looks like
 [image]

I know how to filter the array when i clicked just one checkbox, for example when i clicked the USD 0 - USD 50, the result will be all item with adult_fee < 50. But i don't know how i can add another condition. I tried $.grep but i can't get it work.

I have array like this, stored in dataModified variable.

[image]

Here's my code

```
var checkVals = [];
    var checks =  $(':checkbox[name^=filter]');
    checks.change(function(){
        var filteredData = [];

        // get all values
        var arr = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get();

        // if no check detected
        var checked = $(this).filter(':checked'); 
        if(!checked.length){
            $(".tours").empty().prepend(data);
            return; 
        }

        // get all the data then filter
        dataModified.map(function(dataMap) {
            return arr.map(function(a){
                return dataMap.filter(function(filteredDatas){
                    // just removing USD then convert to integer
                    adultFee = filteredDatas.adult_fee.replace('USD', '');
                    if(a === "p1") {
                        if(parseInt(adultFee) < 50){
                            // i can get the filtered data
                            console.log(filteredDatas)
                        }
                    }
                });
            })
        })
    });
```

Here's where i add conditions array if user check

```
arr.map(function(cv){
    if(cv === "p1") {
        conditions.push(function(item) {
            adultFee = item.adult_fee.replace('USD', '');
            return parseInt(adultFee) < 50;
        });
    } 
    if(cv === "p2") {
        conditions.push(function(item) {
            adultFee = item.adult_fee.replace('USD', '');
            return parseInt(adultFee) >= 51 && parseInt(adultFee) <= 100;
        });
    }
    if(cv === "p3") {
        conditions.push(function(item) {
            adultFee = item.adult_fee.replace('USD', '');
            return parseInt(adultFee) >= 101 && parseInt(adultFee) <= 200;
        });
    }
});
```

then here's my HTML sample checkbox

```
<ul class="filters">
            <li class="filters__box">
                <p>出発地</p>
                <div class="filter__controller">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="pod-2" name="filter-pod" value="guam">
                    <label for="pod">グアム</label>
                </div>
                <div class="filter__controller">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="pod-1" name="filter-pod" value="hawaii">
                    <label for="pod">ハワイ </label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="filters__box">
                <p>価格</p>
                <div class="filter__controller">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="price-1" name="filter-price" value="p1">
                    <label for="price">USD 0 ~ USD 50</label>
                </div>
                <div class="filter__controller">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="price-2" name="filter-price" value="p2">
                    <label for="price">USD 51 ~ USD 100</label>
                </div>
                <div class="filter__controller">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="price-3" name="filter-price" value="p3">
                    <label for="price">USD 101 ~ USD 200</label>
                </div>
                <div class="filter__controller">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="price-4" name="filter-price" value="p4">
                    <label for="price">USD  201 ~ USD 300</label>
                </div>
                <div class="filter__controller">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="price-5" name="filter-price" value="p5">
                    <label for="price">USD 301 ~</label>
                </div>
            </li>
</ul>
```

sample json file for dataModified

```
[
  {
    "seller": "seller",
    "title": "title31",
    "point_of_departure": "グアム",
    "adult_fee": "USD 35.00",
    "image": "https://samplesite.com/upload/fl/500x750/2017/08/599e6b9221171.JPG",
    "reservation_link": "https://samplesite.com",
    "operating_company": "-",
    "guide": false,
    "japanese_support": false,
    "departure_time_zone": "午後",
    "required": "-",
    "pick_up": false,
    "meal": false,
    "child_participation": false,
    "one_person": "-",
    "credit_card_payment": true,
    "title_fixed": "ホテル受取・返却で便利Wi-Fiルーターレンタル",
    "image_fixed": "https://samplesite.com/08/599e6b9221171.JPG",
    "tag": 1
  },
  {
    "seller": "seller",
    "title": "title 4",
    "point_of_departure": "グアム",
    "adult_fee": "USD 135.00",
    "image": "https://samplesite.com/upload/fl/500x750/2017/08/599e6b9221171.JPG",
    "reservation_link": "https://samplesite.com",
    "operating_company": "-",
    "guide": false,
    "japanese_support": false,
    "departure_time_zone": "午後",
    "required": "-",
    "pick_up": false,
    "meal": false,
    "child_participation": false,
    "one_person": "-",
    "credit_card_payment": true,
    "title_fixed": "ホテル受取・返却で便利Wi-Fiルーターレンタル",
    "image_fixed": "https://samplesite.com/08/599e6b9221171.JPG",
    "tag": 2
  },
  {
    "seller": "seller",
    "title": "title 2",
    "point_of_departure": "グアム",
    "adult_fee": "USD 145.00",
    "image": "https://samplesite.com/upload/fl/500x750/2017/08/599e6b9221171.JPG",
    "reservation_link": "https://samplesite.com",
    "operating_company": "-",
    "guide": false,
    "japanese_support": false,
    "departure_time_zone": "午後",
    "required": "-",
    "pick_up": false,
    "meal": false,
    "child_participation": false,
    "one_person": "-",
    "credit_card_payment": true,
    "title_fixed": "ホテル受取・返却で便利Wi-Fiルーターレンタル",
    "image_fixed": "https://samplesite.com/08/599e6b9221171.JPG",
    "tag": 3
  },
  {
    "seller": "seller",
    "title": "title 3",
    "point_of_departure": "グアム",
    "adult_fee": "USD 312.00",
    "image": "https://samplesite.com/upload/fl/500x750/2017/08/599e6b9221171.JPG",
    "reservation_link": "https://samplesite.com",
    "operating_company": "-",
    "guide": false,
    "japanese_support": false,
    "departure_time_zone": "午後",
    "required": "-",
    "pick_up": false,
    "meal": false,
    "child_participation": false,
    "one_person": "-",
    "credit_card_payment": true,
    "title_fixed": "ホテル受取・返却で便利Wi-Fiルーターレンタル",
    "image_fixed": "https://samplesite.com/08/599e6b9221171.JPG",
    "tag": 3
  }
]
```

Comment: can you please include the array also, or please create a snippet which is more better

Comment: @AkhilAravind hi, i include the json content.

Comment: the value checked cannot be found in the array, make sure the checkbox value are available in array also

Comment: @AkhilAravind i checked value then if true, i added it to array. check the post, i edited it along with the code.

Comment: The problem here is everything gets pushed to array, but what to filter ?? key is missing. When I check  the checkbox , I got english value, ( not the price range thing ), but that value is missing in array.

Comment: the thing is, whenever the user clicks, the checkbox has value, that in condition for example is equal to "p1" then it will return specific condition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207233/discussion-between-akhil-aravind-and-marky939).

Comment: could you please take a look at the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e7rdt86m/2/